# React and Three.js constructor Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, three.js

So I think the error is because Im using a three.js constructor inside of react, which uses constructors differently

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
import Detector from 'detector-webgl';
this.THREE =THREE;
const OrbitControls = require("three-orbit-controls")(this.THREE);

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.THREE = THREE;
    class Game{
    constructor(){
        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        this.container;
        this.player = { };
        this.stats;
        this.controls;
        this.camera;
        this.scene;
        this.renderer;
```

Comment: Please, rephrase your question and post minimal, working example. Also an error, if there's any.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better, but your error doesn't seem to be part of that code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
import Detector from 'detector-webgl';
this.THREE =THREE;
const OrbitControls = require("three-orbit-controls")(this.THREE);

class Game{
  constructor(){
    if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
    this.container;
    this.player = { };
    this.stats;
    this.controls;
    this.camera;
    this.scene;
    this.renderer;
      ...

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.THREE = THREE;
    this.Game = new Game;
    ...
```

Comment: yeah i should have copy and pasted the whole thing. Im using ion-phaser package to make 2d games now